# creating bibliography with natbib as an individually numbered section

Tags: numbering, natbib

hi I'm using natbib with an "apalike" style. When I generate the bibliography at the end of my document it is titles "references". Is there a way to have the title numbered in line with my other sections?

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}
\usepackage{natbib}

\begin{document}
\bibliographystyle{apalike}


\section{Overview} displayed as section number 1

\section{Scientific Interest} displayed as section number 2

\section{Research Question}

\section{Theoretical Background / Literature Review}

\section{Hypotheses}
\section{Methods}

\bibliography{jab} ---> HERE I WANT IT TO BE DISPLAYED AS "8 References"
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

`natbib` defines `\bibsection` as a starred section in `article` class. You can redefine it by

`\renewcommand\bibsection{\section{\refname}}`

in your preamble.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}
\usepackage{natbib}
\renewcommand\bibsection{\section{\refname}}

\begin{document}
\bibliographystyle{apalike}


\section{Overview} displayed as section number 1

\section{Scientific Interest} displayed as section number 2

\section{Research Question}

\section{Theoretical Background / Literature Review}

\section{Hypotheses}
\section{Methods}

\bibliography{jab} %%---> HERE I WANT IT TO BE DISPLAYED AS "8 References"
\end{document}
```

[image]